# How to unbind the foreign key related relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to delete the foreign key?

I have two models:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(to=Parent, null=True, related_name="children", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)


class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    def unbind_children(self):  # there I want to unbind all children
        # how to realize this?
```

I want to unbind the child, I means I want to make the special Parent related `Child` instance's parent field to be `None`.

Comment: You may have more than one child. Which one should unbind?

Comment: The first thing you should be aware of: `unbind_children` would be a more appropriate name since there can be many. Additionally you used `Parent` before defining it.

Comment: @JPG I want to unbind all children.

Comment: @qg_java_17137 Added an answer. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **`self.children.update(parent=None)`**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    def unbind_child(self):
        self.children.update(parent=None)
```